# Changing the pre-amplifier gain

Tags: audio, kits

I want to change the gain of this pre-ampilifier I assemvled from a kit.  If change the value of resistor R1 or R4, should I then change the values ​​of other elements?

I'm thinking about changing R1 from 330R to 220R:

[image]

Comment: Aren't P1 and P2 for setting the gain?

Comment: They are, but i want little more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gain of an inverting op-amp amplifer is given by \$A = -\frac {R_f}{R_i}  = \frac {P_1}{R1} = \frac {10k}{330} = 30\$ maximum when the wiper is all the way to the left.

The second stage has a maximum gain of -10. The combined circuit has a maximum gain of -30 × -10 = +300.

Changing R1 to 220 Ω would increase the gain but would increase the loading on the signal source and this may reduce the gain somewhat. Since R4 is driven by the low output impedance of IC1A you wouldn't have that problem there.